# Java heap space error when trying to create an NGram model

Tags: java, arraylist, heap-memory, n-gram

> In part of a larger project I need to create an NGram model using Java which is not optimal nor optional I am using JDK 20 and vs code to run the code. When I try to run the code on vs code I get:

```
`      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:710)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:635)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:618)
        at Ngram.NGramNode.addNGram(NGramNode.java:277)
        at Ngram.NGramNode.addNGram(NGramNode.java:280)
        at Ngram.NGram.addNGramSentence(NGram.java:157)
        at com.glmadu.editdistance.TRspellChecker.getCorpus(TRspellChecker.java:68)
        at com.glmadu.editdistance.TRspellChecker.checkFileSpell(TRspellChecker.java:22)
        at com.glmadu.App.main(App.java:21)`
```

Error I did increase the heap space from launch.JSON to 8GB and the corpus file is around 750 MB the code piece is here

```
private static void getCorpus(String output) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> corpus = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/to/corpus"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(" "); //line 63
                ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String token : tokens) {
                    sentence.add(token); // line 68
                }
                corpus.add(sentence);
            }
            NGram<String> nGram = new NGram<>(corpus, 2);
            nGram.saveAsText(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I do not understand how can I still get Heap space after push it to 8GB I tried with 12 and 10 but I get

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: failed reallocation of scalar replaced objects
`        at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:3138)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:3212)
        at com.glmadu.editdistance.TRspellChecker.getCorpus(TRspellChecker.java:63)
        at com.glmadu.editdistance.TRspellChecker.checkFileSpell(TRspellChecker.java:22)
        at com.glmadu.App.main(App.java:21)
`
```

error when I do that. I am using vs code to run this. Thanks in advance

I tried increasing the heap size, I tried reading less lines still got error even when I tried to read first 1000 lines. I tried not saving NGram model and from that I can derive it's not the NGram modeling but mode like arrays take too much space in memory, also when I checked the memory usage from task manager it sits at 4-5 GB and does not get close to 8 I allocated

Comment: What ngram lib are you using? Have you tried to debug your code? 
Try to watch and inspect your memory consumption by using [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/).

Comment: The error on `split` sounds like your file has the wrong line breaks, so you read the whole file as one line. Windows uses \r\n, Linux uses \n, Mac uses \r.

Comment: sorry I was not clear, when I set heap space to 8 GB line 68 is "corpus.add(sentence)", which makes me think it is something to do with ArrayList. When I increase the heap space which is second trace I provided line 63 IS THE split but in my understanding which may be lacking the buffered reader does read one line than I "split" that line

Comment: You can increase the speed and improve the memory consumption by initializing your `ArrayList` variables with reasonable sizes. The default is 10 and especially for your `corpus` it should equal the line number in your file. Otherwise the VM has to copy the `ArrayList` often when it grows.

Comment: I suggest you step through your program in debug mode and look at the `line` value.

Comment: Another memory optimization: Instead of the `while` loop do  `reader.lines().map(line -> line.split(" ")).map(Arrays::asList).forEach(copus::add);`

Comment: @Sascha I did and indeed it is more than "one" line but it still should be processable because at the most it is 5 lines, now I did not check the whole file but it seemed consistent in lines

Comment: Did you give the `corpus` variable an appropriate size, like `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> corpus = new ArrayList<>(1_000_000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here is how I "solved" the problem I set an initial array size according with @Sascha 's response but it still got problems so I divided the problem and merged them later on

```
public static void getCorpus(String output) {
    int count = 0;
    int countMain = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("path\to\corpus"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            if (count > ARRAY_SIZE) {
                NGram nGram = new NGram(corpus, 2);
                saveNgram(output, nGram, countMain);
                countMain++;
                System.out.println("Clearing ArrayList " + countMain);
                corpus.clear();
                count = 0;
            }
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String token : tokens) {
                sentence.add(token);
            }
            corpus.add(sentence);
        }
        countMain++;
        NGram nGram = new NGram(corpus, 2);
        corpus.clear();
        nGram.saveAsText(output + "final");
        String outFile = output + "final" + ".txt";
        FileWriter fWrite = new FileWriter(outFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedWriter bfWrite = new BufferedWriter(fWrite);

        for (int i = 0; i <= countMain; i++) {
            String path = output + "_part" + i + ".txt";

            mergeNGram(path, outFile, bfWrite);
        }
        fWrite.close();
        bfWrite.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It takes a String path to output file after that to save it runs saveNgram which is quite basic as it takes the output concatenate it to add partx to it and saves the NGram

```
 private static void saveNgram(String outputPath, NGram nGram, int countMain) {
        String finalPath = outputPath + "_part" + countMain + ".txt";
        File nFile = new File(finalPath);
        if (!nFile.exists()) {
            nGram.saveAsText(finalPath);
        }
    }
```

At the and if there are any leftover lines saves it again and calls mergeNGram which is just a BufferedReader/Writer to write to the final file

```
   private static void mergeNGram(String path, String output, BufferedWriter bfWrite) {
        File inFile = new File(path);
        try (FileReader fRead = new FileReader(inFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            BufferedReader bfRead = new BufferedReader(fRead);
            String Line;
            while ((Line = bfRead.readLine()) != null) {
                bfWrite.write(Line);
                bfWrite.write(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            bfWrite.flush();
            bfRead.close();
            fRead.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It is nowhere near perfect but it solves my current problem and that is all I can do at the moment, special thanks to @Sascha for the help I am leaving this here so anyone with similar problem can find and adopt